# How can I execute a rollback action in Install4j regardless of what rollback barriers I've passed?

Tags: logging, rollback, install4j

I want to send the install4j install log file to my server if the installation fails. The best way I could find to do this was with an action that does what I need in the rollback. The problem is if I have rollback barriers, then I have to add another one of these actions after each rollback barrier for it to work. Going forward, I may change my rollback barriers, but forget to also change my log actions along with them, which makes maintenance a lot more difficult.

Is there a way to make an action's rollback execute no matter how many rollback barriers the installer has passed, or is there maybe a better way to grab the log than with rollbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an event listener to react to a rollback regardless of any rollback barriers:

```
context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
    public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == EventType.CANCELLING) {
            // Add rollback code here
        }
    }
});
```